# Update a column in a pandas dataframe based on the values in 2 other columns and the previous value in a 4th column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a row with event_type 'modify', I want to possibly update the value in the 'state' column in the same row to the previous value in the 'state' column with the same 'vm_id'.

Given the following dataframe:

```
   vm_id  vdc_id          event_time event_type    state
0      1     100 2023-06-22 17:10:00     create   active
1      1     100 2023-06-22 18:10:00     deploy  running
2      1     100 2023-06-22 19:10:00     modify   active <-
3      2     100 2023-06-22 20:10:00     create   active
4      2     100 2023-06-22 21:10:00     modify   active <-
5      2     100 2023-06-22 22:10:00     deploy  running
```

I want to update it to this data frame.

```
   vm_id  vdc_id          event_time event_type    state
0      1     100 2023-06-22 17:10:00     create   active
1      1     100 2023-06-22 18:10:00     deploy  running
2      1     100 2023-06-22 19:10:00     modify  running <-
3      2     100 2023-06-22 20:10:00     create   active
4      2     100 2023-06-22 21:10:00     modify   active <-
5      2     100 2023-06-22 22:10:00     deploy  running
```

For the 'modify' event_type in row 2 in the first dataframe, the previous row with the same vm_id = 1 has state == 'running', so I want to update state to 'running' in the row with the 'modify'.  For the second modify in row 4 in the first table, its previous row with the same vm_id = 2 has state == 'active' so I want to leave state as active in row 4. I can either leave it as is, or if it is easier to just always copy the previous row with the same event_id's state value to the 'state' column in teh row with a modify is ok too.

I have completely taxed my df.loc, df.query() and shift skills.  The combination of updating a second column based on a third column and the the columns previous value has me completely befuddled.

One idea I've been working on is to sort by vm_id and then time.  Then I could check the previous record by index and if the vm_id matches, then copy the value from the 'state' column to the modify record.  I am concerned about performance, though as the number of records gets larger.

OK - here is my attempt at it:

```
df[(df['vm_id'].shift() == df['vm_id']) &  
   (df['event_type'] == 'modify'), df['state']] = df['state'].shift()
```

This gives me:  TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

---

Well, I think I've found a problem.  Its something I didn't explictly specify because I thought it was included in my question.

If I expand the dataframe:

```
0      1     100 2023-06-23 16:00:00     create   active
1      1     100 2023-06-23 16:10:00     deploy   running
2      1     100 2023-06-23 16:20:00     modify   active <-
3      1     100 2023-06-23 16:25:00     modify   active <-
4      1     100 2023-06-23 16:30:00     modify   active <-
5      2     100 2023-06-23 16:35:00     create   active
6      2     100 2023-06-23 16:40:00     modify   active
7      2     100 2023-06-23 16:45:00     deploy   running

Notice the 3 modify events in a row.  This is a valid scenario.  When I run either solution on this dataframe, I get:

 
**index vm_id  vdc_id        event_time event_type   state**
0      1     100 2023-06-23 16:00:00     create   active
1      1     100 2023-06-23 16:10:00     deploy   running
2      1     100 2023-06-23 16:20:00     modify   running <-
3      1     100 2023-06-23 16:25:00     modify   active  <-
4      1     100 2023-06-23 16:30:00     modify   active  <-
5      2     100 2023-06-23 16:35:00     create   active
6      2     100 2023-06-23 16:40:00     modify   active
7      2     100 2023-06-23 16:45:00     deploy   running


It should look like this:


**index vm_id  vdc_id        event_time event_type   state**
0      1     100 2023-06-23 16:00:00     create   active
1      1     100 2023-06-23 16:10:00     deploy  running
2      1     100 2023-06-23 16:20:00     modify  running <-
3      1     100 2023-06-23 16:25:00     modify  running <-
4      1     100 2023-06-23 16:30:00     modify  running <-
5      2     100 2023-06-23 16:35:00     create  active
6      2     100 2023-06-23 16:40:00     modify  active
7      2     100 2023-06-23 16:45:00     deploy  running
```

When there are multiple modify events in a row, the first modify is updated just like it is supposed to.  But, in this case, the next 2 are not.  I'd like to change active to running for those as well.  In the 2 modify events that did not get upated, they are modify events that should have its 'state' updated to 'running' as well since the second one now is a modify event where the previous row with the same 'vm_id' has its state set to 'running'.  Then when the second one is updated, the third one now should have its state updated to 'running'.

I am trying to think how to specify the solution so that the other 2 modify events will get updated.
Maybe the modify state should be updated from the previous non-modify event in the same vm_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is sorted by `vm_id` and in time order (as in your sample) then you could use the code as below. This works by convertin all `modify` rows to None status and then forward filling with the last not-None value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "vm_id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "vdc_id": [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
        "event_type": ["create", "deploy", "modify", "modify", "modify","create", "modify", "deploy"],
        "status": ["active", "running", "active", "active", "active", "active", "active", "running"],
    })

print(df)

df["status"] = df["status"].mask(df["event_type"].eq("modify"), None).ffill()

print(df)
```

This gives:

```
   vm_id  vdc_id event_type   status
0      1     100     create   active
1      1     100     deploy  running
2      1     100     modify   active
3      1     100     modify   active
4      1     100     modify   active
5      2     100     create   active
6      2     100     modify   active
7      2     100     deploy  running

   vm_id  vdc_id event_type   status
0      1     100     create   active
1      1     100     deploy  running
2      1     100     modify  running
3      1     100     modify  running
4      1     100     modify  running
5      2     100     create   active
6      2     100     modify   active
7      2     100     deploy  running
```

If the data is not sorted by `vm_id` then a groupby approach could be used and the groups modified as the code above.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for.  I need to understand groupby better.

Comment: Will the apply be a possible performance issue?  I think I'll be OK in the short term, but I am expecting the number of vm_ids to grow quite larege.

Comment: See revised answer. Previously I ignored the sorted order as in your data sample in case it was not so arranged in larger data sets. You will see that `apply` is otherwise not needed. Your implication that `apply` can be somewhat slow for very large data sets is true - it uses Python code not compiled, vectorized code but whether this is an issue depends on your requirements. In any case the answer illustrates the groupby approach.

Comment: Thank you again.  This looks good and makes sense.  The data will be sorted by event_time.  I am considering sorting the data by (vm_id, event_time).  But its good to know that I can use group by if the extra sort by vm_id starts taking to long.

Comment: OK - when expanding the number of events I've uncovered a problem.  I didn't explicitly mention this because I thougt it was included in my question,

Comment: I updated the second half of my question to detail what the problem is.  There is a case where there are Modify records that should have its state updated but they aren't.  It is when there are multiple modify records in a row.

Comment: OK. With this new data format, it is simpler to use a different approach. See my changed answer. This uses forward filling which will deal with any number of 'modify' rows. Should be reasonably fast for large data sets. I have not re-iterated the groupby code but you already have that.

Comment: Perfect.  I am also going to work with developing  the groupby version to compare.   Thank you.

Comment: Please accept the answer to show issue is now resolved (click on the accept box). My tests show this code should process 100ks rows in a few seconds. `groupby apply` sends a subset of the DF (the group) to the function so the code can be directly used if required for non-sorted data.